# Allow re-applying to a previously applied to job via Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I had applied for a job found via Careers.Stackoverflow last year, and ended up going in a different direction.  Earlier this week I saw that they had relisted the job, for which I was still a good fit.  Because I previously applied for the job, I'm not able to resubmit my information; no "Apply Now" button is displayed.

I would think that one should be able to reapply for a job.

Comment: If he retracted his previous application himself, right? Because re-applying if employer found someone a bad fit would be pretty annoying for employers.

Comment: Is it possible to retract an application?  I don't see any option in my Inbox and the employer never responded via the site to my application, so I can't respond to it via my own Inbox (it says "You must wait for the employer to respond"; after almost a year I don't think it's happening lol), but I also have no way to contact the company to resubmit my application.

Most career sites will say that you applied for a position, but still let you resend a resume.  Seems like Careers.SO should as well.